# fabricjs IText: overlapping character background-color making lines when semitransparent

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I got a problem with ovelapping characters in my itext objects.[image] 
As shown in the image, the letter-backgrounds are somehow having a wrong offset or/and width. 
I can't trace down the error. Maybe it's some css on my site, but i don't know how the css could affect the itext object.
[image: With object padding set to 0]
This is how it looks like with object padding set to 0. The width exceeds the right boundary!

I have tried to reproduce the error in a fiddle, but off course with no success. 
https://jsfiddle.net/FlemmingH/z74whhtn/

```
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('canv');

var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('BOX', {
  left: -200,
  top: 20,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: '#333',
  lineHeight: 1.1,
  styles: {
    0: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.3)' , fontSize: 420 },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)', fontSize: 420  },
      2: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)', fontSize: 420  }

    }
  }
});
canvas.add(iTextSample);
```

**EDIT 1 - Rounding-error in fabric.js ???**
Ok, now the error is reproducible! Try to manually scale up this IText object: [IText fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FlemmingH/uq85Lf3j/)
It seems like there's kind of a rounding error getting visible when scaling up from a small font size (in the fiddle i used fontSize:20).

As shown in the picture below there's still an error even with a fontSize:120.[image]

So is the only option to get around this by initializing the IText object with a big fontsize and then force the user to scale it down ?

Comment: Everything works now in v1.6.7 ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this issue to the fabricjs issue tracker.
This is a bug.
I'm pushing a fix to solve it.
There is an extra 1px calculation in the width of the character.